# Unable to perform zonal statistics in Python because of affine error

Tags: python, raster, geopandas, rasterio, zonal-statistics

I have a raster layer and a polygons layer I want to use for zonal statistics, however these two files may be in a completely different projection and CRS. I am trying to use the following python code to perform this operation, specifically finding the mean pixel value of the raster layer within the many polygons of the polygons layer:

```py
polygons = gpd.read_file('polygons.shp')
raster = r'raster.tif'
raster = rasterio.open(raster)
array = raster.read(1)
affine = raster.affine
zs_polygons = zonal_stats(polygons, array, affine=affine, stats=['mean'])
zs_polygons
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_732/3013467903.py in <module>
      9 raster = rasterio.open(raster)
     10 array = raster.read(1)
---> 11 affine = raster.affine
     12 zs_roads = zonal_stats(polygons, array, affine=affine, stats=['mean'])
     13 zs_roads

AttributeError: 'DatasetReader' object has no attribute 'affine'
```

I am not sure how to address this error message or where I went wrong in my code. When I opened my raster and vector layers up to view in QGIS, I saw that they did not line up, and so I am thinking maybe this issue is because the project/CRS are not lined up, but I am not sure. How can I address my error so that my code can properly find the average raster pixel values within each polygon, and then append this average values in a new column to the input polygons shapefile?

For reference I checked the CRS of the vector and raster layer using the ".crs" function in Python and found:

Vector polygons:

```
PROJCS["MM5_sphere",GEOGCS["GCS_Sphere",DATUM["D_custom",SPHEROID["custom",6370000,0]],PRIMEM["custom",0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",37],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-120.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",30],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Raster:

```
 LOCAL_CS["NAD83 / Conus Albers",UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Comment: I guess you meant `affine = raster.transform` Read the docs:   https://autogis-site.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Raster/zonal-statistics.html

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I just changed that, and ran it, and now got this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`, which is confusing because I never used a `get` function anywhere.

Comment: This source is where I saw it should be written `affine = raster.affine`: https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/lessons/L6/zonal-statistics.html

Comment: That link is 4 years old and the `affine` keyword was removed in rasterio v1 https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migrating-to-v1.html#tickets.